# Data Vault on Snowflake - what timestamp data type should be used for load_datetime attributes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Data Vault, all objects have a load_datetime attribute which can be used to determine the relative order of insertion into the database, regardless of where in the world this took place.

Which Snowflake data type is best suited for such columns and why?

My own feeling is that timestamp_ntz would not work as it just records "wallclock" time.

I would think that timestamp_ltz is the best choice as it stores only UTC.

Also, timestamp_tz should maintain the correct relative order, but the local time information is irrelevant in this case so timestamp_ltz seems a cleaner choice.

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that using _ltz (UTC) is the best choice, especially if you have sources coming from different time zones. If all your sources are local to a single time zone then _tz would be fine, but why risk it right?

Comment: Did you mean _ntz rather than _tz in the scenario that all sources are within the same time zone?

_tz should be OK for sources spread over different time zones as it includes a time zone component doesn't it?

Comment: Yes - my bad. _ntz to keep the timezone if that is a requirement to know the timezone.